# Angular functional route guard with ngrx store

Tags: routes, functional-programming, ngrx, store, guard

I've searched everywhere and I've only been able to find the deprecated class-based Canactivate implementation of a route guard that accesses an ngrx store.

Can someone provide an example of a functional route guard that accesses an ngrx store?

Answer (score 1):

The implementation would be the same.
The only difference is that you don't inject the store with the constructor, but that you're using the new `inject` method provided by Angular.

```
export function myRouterGuard(): Observable<boolean|UrlTree> {
  const store = inject(Store);

  // implementation comes here
}
```